# Converting from radians/samples to normalized frequency range $[0.0, 1.0]$?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, conversion, scipy

I'm trying to understand [the following code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192640/4959635), specifically how to use the results of [scipy.signal.freqz](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) where `w` in `w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=8000)` is in radians/samples.

I need to convert this to the range of $[0.0, 1.0]$ where $0.5$ corresponds to Nyquist frequency and $1.0$ to sample rate. And I'm trying to figure out the smartest way of doing this and whether I can use a general ["any number range to any number range" algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929103/convert-a-number-range-to-another-range-maintaining-ratio) or whether the radians/samples unit poses some problems regarding this?

**NOTE:**
I know [how to convert frequency from $\textrm{Hz}$ to radians-per-sample](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/7907/16003).

Comment: Also is the [0.0, 1.0] range possibly called cycles/samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted in your comment, the normalized frequency range `[0, 1)` cycles/sample corresponds to the range `[0, 2*pi)` radians/sample. Therefore, given a frequency in the `[0, 1)` range, simply multiply by `2*pi` to convert to radians/sample.

Comment: So do I get from rads/samples to cycles/samples by dividing by 2*pi the rads/samples?

Comment: Yes, that's right.